# Can't read vcf-derived file in R: "no lines available in input"

Tags: r, file-format

I have a vcf file and I want to extract the header (which is the only line that has the pattern '#CHROM' on it. So, on the mac terminal I typed the following:

```
grep '#CHROM' file.vcf > headerlinevcf.txt
```

I see it on the terminal, or in vi, and I found what I expected. I can see all the columns of that line (= the text in the header). I see it like this:

```
#CHROM POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO FORMAT HG00096 HG00097 ...
```

Now, I try to read it into R as a vector, because I have to do some other stuff to it, and the following error comes up:

```
> headerline<-as.vector(read.table('headerlinevcf.txt'))
 Error in read.table("headerlinevcf.txt") : no lines available in input
```

I tried to read.delim using tab and then a space, but it didn't work. I also tried:

```
headerline <- read.table('headerlinevcf.txt')
```

And also gives back the same error.
I also tried readLines command, and it gives me this:

```
headerline <- readLines('headerlinevcf.txt')
> headerline[1]
[1] 
"#CHROM\tPOS\tID\tREF\tALT\tQUAL\tFILTER\tINFO\tFORMAT\tHG00096\tHG00097\tH
G00099\tHG00100\tHG00101\tHG00102\tHG00103\tHG00105\tHG00106\tHG00107\tHG00
... <truncated>
```

It seems that the VCF file (and thus this VCF-derived) have some strange way of delimitation. 
A friend tried in Python to read it, change the '\t' into spaces, and open that new file with R, but the same error came out once again.

I don't know that well this kind of format to find the error that easy, so I've been struggling with this the past couple of days. Please, if someone knows what's happening lend me a hand! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the `comment.char=` argument to `read.table()`.

Comment: Seems like `scan()` would be the more appropriate function in this case if you just want to read a vector of strings. Try `scan('headerlinevcf.txt', "character")` As Martin pointed out, normally the pound sign (#) is used as a comment character in the read() functions so that like would be skipped.

Comment: @MrFlick I used scan (which I didn't know) and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!